# Importing in node is not recognising the * symbol

Tags: node.js, tensorflow

I recently started using imports in node.js (v12.4.0) and specifically with the following statement

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs-node';
```

and I get the following error

```
 import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs-node';
        ^
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```

and there doesn't seem to be anyone with this error, clearly my ignorance but can someone help me out with why this happened and how to solve it?

Comment: Remember to follow all the necessary special steps if you want to use ES modules: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

Comment: Use "--experimental-modules" flag or whatever it is.

Comment: I've added this import within an app started with pm2 so im not sure how to use --experimental-modules with it